# Form Key Value in template and controller

Tags: controllers, frontend, form-validation, magento-1.9.2.1, form-key

The following function is used to get the form key in templates with type hidden. My customerController.php does not validate the form key with the method `_validateFormKey()`. When I echo the following function in controller, Its value differ from the value that is posted in form.

```
 echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();
```

My question is

1. How can I validate this form key?
2. Why form key in template is different from the form key in Controller?

In my template file

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

but in my controller,

```
echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('form_key'); // IZwYiobh1jmXLdBG

echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); // DzMQebo8poku9ZKa
```

Comment: How did you fix this? I am also getting the same issue.

Answer (score 10):

### Pass form_key:

For *Validate form key* ,you need to **send the form key with URL** or as a  **hidden input.**

If you send as URL parameter then the parameter name should be **form_key/[keyValue]**.

If send as hidden field then you need to send as

```
 <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

### Validated form Key

For *validated form key at controller* you need to add below code:

```
 if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
  $this->_redirect('*/*');
  return;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Amit,  I have updated my question in accordance with your solution. Why form key changes when calling the form key with core/session?

Comment: But **_validateFormKey()** always redirect because posted form key is and one I get from core session is different.

Comment: Please check cookie and session at admin

Comment: Would you be open to submit a PR here? https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/issues/1287

Comment: which form (or block code) and controller are used here exactly?

Answer (score 2):

To get your form_key validated in **Magento 2.1**, you need to place

```
<?php / @noEscape / echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

Right after your FORM tag and before all input elements, in your .phtml template file.

Comment: where to place that in which module ?

Comment: Add it in your template file, right after your opening <form> tag and before all input elements. It's the easiest way and works.

Comment: Even after adding that, it shows invalid form key error often. Why?

Comment: Have you cleaned cache? Or, it could be some issue with session saving...